# Has something replaced bundleconfig.json in ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

When I create a new ASP.NET MVC Core targeting 2.1 RC1, it doesn't create the bundleconfig.json file which is used for bundling and minification. This file is  created if I target 2.0.

Here is a example, the solution contains a new project targeting 2.0 and another targeting 2.1:
[image]

Has something replaced the builtin bundling and minification, or is this just a bug in RC1?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

bundleconfig.json was removed from the 2.1 templates because it relied on a tool not created or supported by Microsoft. See https://github.com/aspnet/templating/issues/326.

> This file [bundleconfig.json] is for configuring the various incantations of the BundlerMinifier tool, which isn't actually shipped in the templates, or supported by Microsoft.

The ASP.NET Core team has replaced bundleconfig with "libman". Rightclick the project --> Add --> Client Side Library and add the packages you need

Comment: Thank you, I noticed BundlerMinifier requires a Nuget package install to work. I've been playing with LibMan last week i didn't realize it handled bundling and minificantion, the docs and examples are light. Also it didn't make the final cut for 15.7, you have install 15.8 Preview to use. I understand the logic for removing, but since LibMan was removed from 15.7, there will will a gap with the templates since .NET Core 2.1 will go RTM before 15.8 is released. As much as I like ASP.NET Core, there is too much flux and confusion with client side package management.

Comment: Although Nuget had its limitations, it was had worked well enough for many of us for client-sde library management. I wish more effort could have been put to make it work with ASP.NET Core, which would have saved us from   trying figure out what combination of Bower, npm, glup, grunt, webpack and LibMan to use.

Comment: Didn't realize it had been cut from VS 15.7. I'm always using preview builds of VS so thought it had been released to the stable channel.

Comment: Also, yes NuGet wasn't really well designed for client side library management. I've been using yarn and webpack with aspnetcore and it works well for my team

Comment: The problem is the current state of ASP.NET Core 2.1 and VS 2017 15.8 (preview), we are left with no built-in client-side package management, bundling or minification. For a developer coming from ASP.NET MVC 5, it is disappointing to use the default template and realize the JavaScript files are static, and left with the annoyance of sinking time to researching client-side library management. Again, I know NuGet client-side had limitations, but it was good enough for apps with a small number of libraries, but wanted to be able to have dependency management and centralize update management.

Comment: Are you using the Yarn Installer ( https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.YarnInstaller ) for VS?

Comment: I'm using the Yarn.MSBuild package which invokes yarn commands as MSBuild targets. This is mostly for CI builds, though. Primarily using VS Code so it's easy to run commands from integrated command line, such as run 'webpack --watch', to build client side-assets separately from .NET

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, I was able to copy over an existing bundle file into the project and that worked for me.  You do need to [follow this guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x) and install the Bundle & Minifier extension … also, make sure you are using VS 15.7.

It does look like the bundle file is not included in the latest project template.

Comment: I'm using 15.7.1. I did get it working by adding the file manually but I'm wondering why they would have removed it. I'm wondering if something is replacing it.

Answer (score 4):

*Note that this works for net core 2.2, not sure about 2.1. Also note that as of net core 3, it appears 'local tools' should (must?) be used instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#local-tools.*

Finally had success configuring pre-build bundling using the (as of writing) recommended `BundlerMinifier.Core` package.

Add the following to your .csproj file:

```xml
  <!-- 
       WARNING: don't update to latest version of BundlerMinifier.Core (as of 3.2.435)! 
         3.0.415 is the latest version that appears to work with this method of
         automating bundling/minification 
  -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="3.0.415" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="3.0.415" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="RestoreToolsAndBundle" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="dotnet tool restore" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet bundle" WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" />
  </Target>
```

Note that this should be *all* that you need; you shouldn't need the 'Bundler & Minifier' VS extension, nor the 'BuildBundlerMinifier' package.

Attempt a build and you'll hopefully see in `Output` that bundling and minification have completed, as per your `bundleConfig.json`.

Comment: Thank you! This is _literally the only_ solution that I have found that actually works.

Answer (score 3):

Also, as of 2021, please consider my answer on similar SO question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66659756/5101

TL;DR; - Use WebOptimizer Core nuget package, by Mads Kristensen, for .NET Core 3+ and .NET 5+

Answer (score 1):

Just add BuildBundlerMinifier Nuget to project, and rebuild it

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Bundler and Minifier on my ASP.NET Core MVC project. When I right-clicked **Bundler and Minifier > Bundle File**, it made a `bundleconfig.json` for me, which I could then set to bundle on each build. Publishing my web app to Azure sent the correct minified CSS and JS files.

One disadvantage is that you have to minify each file, which doesn't matter for me since I have 2, but I imagine most real projects will have many more than that.